# CakePhp mail not working (smtp)

Tags: php, email, cakephp, smtp, gmail

I am looking a site. I'm new in this site and I don't know CakePhp. This site has users and I try do a **forgot password page**. I searched but can't a way or missed that.

UsersController.php

```html
 ...
 if ($this->User->save($this->data)) {

   App::uses('CakeEmail', 'Network/Email');
   $settings = $this->requestAction('pages/setting');

         $this->email = new CakeEmail('smtp');

         $email = $select['User']['email'];
         $content = sprintf('<body> Sevgili ' . $select['User']['username'] . ", <br>
            Şifre yenileme talebiniz tarafımıza iletilmiştir.
            Aşağıdaki linki tıklayarak yeni şifrenizi belirleyebilirsiniz. <br>
            <a href=\"http://%s/%s\">Buraya Tıklayınız</a> <br>
            Keyifli Gezintiler <br>
            Yukardaki link ile bağlantı sağlayamıyorsanız,
            linki web tarayıcınızın adres bölümüne kopyalayabilirsiniz.</body>", $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $code);

         $this->email->from(array($settings['Setting']['smtp_mail'] => $settings['Setting']['title']))
             ->to($email)
             ->emailFormat('html')
             ->subject('Şifre Yenileme [' . time() . ']');

         if ($this->email->send($content)) {
         $this->Session->setFlash(__('Şifre güncelleme bilgileriniz E-Posta adresinize gönderilmiştir.'), 'default', array('class' => 'success'));
         } else {
         trigger_error("error Mail");
         }

         $this->redirect('forgot');
}
```

And Config/email.php

```html
class EmailConfig {

    public $default = array(
        'transport' => 'Mail',
        'from' => 'you@localhost',

    );

    public $smtp = array(
        'transport' => 'Smtp',
        'from' => array('mymail@gmail.com' => 'Mysite'),
        'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
        'port' => 587,
        'timeout' => 30,
        'username' => 'mymail@gmail.com',
        'password' => 'mypassword',
        'client' => null,
        'log' => true,
        'charset' => 'utf-8',
        'headerCharset' => 'utf-8',
        'tls' => true

    );
```

I say again: I'm new worker on this site and another worker used that codes. I don't know why that codes doesn't work now. And I asked that.
Thanks a lot for all advices.

Comment: in your smtp config, set `tls` to `FALSE`

Comment: I tried but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you get an email on your gmail account saying that a third party is knowing your password?

Comment: No. I didn't get email.

Comment: Well, i did have the same problem, All i did is setting TLS to false and autorizing my Gmail account to send emails. You can find more info here: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255

Comment: I opened the feature you mentioned. But it still has not improved. Can 'log' 'client' and 'timeout' block me? I don't know what they did.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134256/discussion-between-ayaou-and-mymiracl).